# How to identify columns & recategorize data using python?

Tags: python

[image: 1]

I have a very messy dataset that needs to be cleaned up as per the image attached.

I need to transform the datase by:

1. Identifying column header using the string before colon “:” (the actual dataset has a lot more header)
2. Recategorize the data based on the new column header.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution I'm telling you is a standard solution, but here it is:

With this code, I have a dataframe similar to your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    0 : ['RT:123425','VB:543557','JK:34542463','RT:365356'],
    1 : ['VB:331245','PL:783557','VB:12342463','JK:965356'],
    3 : ['PL:122345','JK:543557','PL:56542463','VB:465356'],
    4 : ['PL:222345','RT:143557','JK:99542463','YR:995356']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             0            1            3            4
0    RT:123425    VB:331245    PL:122345    PL:222345
1    VB:543557    PL:783557    JK:543557    RT:143557
2  JK:34542463  VB:12342463  PL:56542463  JK:99542463
3    RT:365356    JK:965356    VB:465356    YR:995356
```

I create an empty dataframe that I want to fill later with appropriate values.

```
mycolumns = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for i in row:
    if i.split(':')[0] not in mycolumns:
      mycolumns.append(i.split(':')[0])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = mycolumns, index = range(df.shape[0]))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    RT   VB   PL   JK   YR
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then I replace every cell that should not be NaN with an empty list:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for i in row:
    df1[str(i.split(':')[0])][index] = []
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    RT  VB   PL   JK   YR
0   []  []   []  NaN  NaN
1   []  []   []   []  NaN
2  NaN  []   []   []  NaN
3   []  []  NaN   []   []
```

I fill the dataframe with the following code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for i in row:
    (df1[str(i.split(':')[0])][index]).append((i.split(':')[1]))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
         RT          VB                PL                    JK        YR
0  [123425]    [331245]  [122345, 222345]                   NaN       NaN
1  [143557]    [543557]          [783557]              [543557]       NaN
2       NaN  [12342463]        [56542463]  [34542463, 99542463]       NaN
3  [365356]    [465356]               NaN              [965356]  [995356]
```